# How to factor this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$3x+2+\frac{1}{3x} = \frac{-4}3$

I was only able to find the solution by plugging it into a program. Never have encountered a problem like this before

Comment: What are you trying to solve for?

Comment: cross multiply to get rid of fractions then factor

Answer (score 4):

Simplify as follows: 
$$ 3x+2+\frac{1}{3x}=\frac{-4}{3}$$
$$ 9x^2+6x+1=-4x$$
$$ 9x^2+1=-10x$$
$$ 9x^2+10x+1=0.$$
I imagine you can take it from here.